# Disable sounds when pressed enter key to append text on richtextbox

Tags: vb.net, richtextbox

I have this in my design form.

[image]

My codes are the follwoing

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    RichTextBox1.AppendText(TextBox1.Text)
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox1_Keyup(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyUp
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then
        Call Button2_Click(sender, e)
    End If
End Sub
```

The problem is when I click on textbox, typed something in it then pressed enter I will hear a beeping sound. That sound is the one that I want to disable.

I also notice that if I just typed in the textbox and click the button I can hear no sound, the sound occurs whenever I clicked on textbox, type something in it and pressed enter.

**EDIT:**

By conducting a thorough research, I realized that the ding sounds doesn't come from button pressed but from the last line of richtextbox. It is the same sound that we can heard when we pressed key_down and we are in the last line of a richtextbox. `How do I disable it?`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just set the [AcceptButton()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.acceptbutton(v=vs.110).aspx) property of the Form to Button2.  Then you don't need the KeyUp code at all:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Me.AcceptButton = Button2
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    RichTextBox1.AppendText(TextBox1.Text)
End Sub

' Don't need this code anymore:
'Private Sub TextBox1_Keyup(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyUp
'    If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then
'        Call Button2_Click(sender, e)
'    End If
'End Sub
```

Comment: thanks for your response Sir. However, I also call the btn_button in other forms. My code in calling button is like this `Call Button2_Click(sender, e)`. So in other form I have this code '
        TextBox1.Text = "asd"
        Call Button2_Click(sender, e)'

Comment: Use `Button2.PerformClick()` instead of calling the method directly.